# How to determine, which user created a record automaticaly?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to automatically update the username, that has created/altered a record, like the datetime/timestamp function?

Or does this only work with triggers?

I'm trying to create a table and i need to add, which user created or modified a certain record.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `salt` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `created_by` VARCHAR(100) -- user?
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You'll need to implement that in either your application or a trigger. There's no built-in function/method for that.

Comment: *"How to determine, which user created a record automaticaly?"* define user in this context it is a MySQL user or application user..

Comment: @RaymondNijland it will be implemented with php, Once a certain user with admin rights is logged into a system and creates a new user, then that user should be stored in the DB

Comment: ok thank u for your input, i will have a look into this

Comment: *"ok thank u for your input, i will have a look into this"* i removed that comment about updateable views..  *"it will be implemented with php, Once a certain user with admin rights is logged into a system and creates a new user, then that user should be stored in the DB"* You need to change the application code.. Only the application knows which application user has started the INSERT command to make a new user..

Comment: Because i saw the salt column iam assuming you are going to use MD5, SHA256, SHA512 salted see [Safe Password Hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) ..

Comment: Because i saw the salt column iam assuming you are going to use "unsafe" hashing methods like MD5 (very unsafe), SHA256 (unsafe because it is fast), SHA512 (unsafe because it is fast) and salt these...See [Safe Password Hashing](https://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) for a beter explainment/method.

Comment: .. also the  `password_hash()` hashes are save against [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) and `password_verify()` makes it safe against [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) as well.   the needed safe SQL is more or less `SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = 'username'` does not use password in the WHERE as well as databases are designed to return data quick especially the case if password column is part of a (multicolumn) index meaning the timing attack also might be possible when you add the password column is in the `WHERE` clause.